# Finding the limit of complex functions

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

I'm having trouble with finding the limit of the following complex function (and complex functions in general):

$$\lim_{z\to0}\frac{ze^{i/z}}{(z^2+a^2)^2}$$

What I've tried is writing $z$ as $r.e^{i\theta}$ which gives me:

$$\frac{1}{a^4}\lim_{z\to0}r.e^{i\theta}.e^{i\frac{e^{-i\theta}}{r}}$$

But that doesn't get me much further. I'm also unsure what this 'transformation' of coordinates means for my limit z. Do I change it to $r\to0$ for every $\theta$?

Comment: It does change your limit to $r \to 0$ for arbitrary $\theta$. Precisely speaking it changes your limit to one involving a new parametrization variable $t$, where $r(t) \to 0$ as $t \to 0^+$ and $\theta(t)$ is an arbitrary continuous function. That said, why do you expect that this limit exists?

Comment: I've plotted it in Wolfram and the limit seems to be zero, it's also necessary for the limit to exist (it's part of an exercise where I need to calculate an integral which equals this limit). I'm integrating over a contour in the complex plane which lies in the top half-plane. I think what my professor did is change the contour to the bottom half-plane so my $\theta$ is negative, which makes the limit 0.

Comment: The limit doesn't exist in general: along $z=it$ as $t \to 0^+$ you get $\infty$ (times a phase factor), but as $t \to 0^-$ you get $0$. The same thing happens along a general line segment: if it's in the upper half plane you get $\infty$ (times a phase factor), if it's in the lower half plane you get $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Try to look at the limit of the modulus bearing in mind that the exponential always has modulus $1$

Comment: No, it doesn't have modulus one. Follow the path $z=it$, then $e^{i/z}=e^{1/t}$, which grows extremely fast as $t \to 0^+$.

Comment: You are right! Misread the $z$ on my smartphone

Comment: Limit doesn't exist because we get different limits depending on the parametrization